# How to set environment variables in Supervisor service

Tags: supervisord

How do you export environment variables in the command executed by Supervisor? I first tried:

```
command="export SITE=domain1; python manage.py command"
```

but Supervisor reports "can't find command".

So then I tried:

```
command=/bin/bash -c "export SITE=domain1; python manage.py command"
```

and the command runs, but this seems to interfere with the daemonization since when I stop the Supervisor daemon, all the other daemons it's running aren't stopped.

Answer (score 115):

To add a single environment variable, You can do something like this.

```
[program:django]
environment=SITE=domain1
command = python manage.py command
```

But, if you want to export multiple environment variables, you need to separate them by comma.

```
[program:django]
environment = 
    SITE=domain1,
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=foo.settings.local,
    DB_USER=foo,
    DB_PASS=bar
command = python manage.py command
```

Comment: How can we do this automatically? Let's say we need to set the environment variable when the server is starting up. so how can we set this to happen with a startup script?

Comment: if the env value may contains another `=` symbol, then need be quotes like this:
```
environment=
  "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096"
```

Answer (score 23):

Just do it separately:

```
environment=SITE=domain1
command=python manage.py command
```

Refer to http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment for more info.

Comment: Environment Variables PORT=8000
command=uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --http :<PORT> How do I use it on the command line?