# how to excute a program with desktop via supervisor

Tags: ubuntu, export, supervisord

1. if i want to run a program with desktop(ubuntu),i will use the command:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0 && python text.py
   ```
2. now i want to use supervisor to monitor test.py,so i add it to .conf file:

   ```
   [program:test]
   command=export DISPLAY=:0 && python test.py
   user=root
   autorestart=true
   redirect_stderr=true
   stdout_logfile=/var/log/test.log
   loglevel=info
   ```
3. but it tell me "can't find command 'export'".

i don't know how to fix it .thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this works. give it a try: __command=/bin/bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0 && python test.py"__

Comment: @vahidabdi [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055951/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-supervisor-service)  this question is similar.i tried this:`code`

Comment: @vahidabdi [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055951/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-supervisor-service)  this question is similar.i tried this:
`
command=gedit
user=root
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/test.log
loglevel=info
environment=DISPLAY=":0"
`
.It works .but if i change the command to "python test.py" it tell me error. The log is "INFO gave up: test entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly"

Comment: Seems ok to me except `python test.py`, use full path of test.py

Comment: @vahidabdi it is full path:command=/usr/bin/python2.7 /root/online/test.py.when i run test.py in shell ,it is ok.but when i put it into supervisor,it will get a error above.I am doubt of that whether this will cause the running environment changes.For example if the test.py use a .conf file in the same path.