# Supervisor not detecting file

Tags: supervisord

I am trying to run a command via a proxy.  When I run this command in shell it works

`http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:29800 /home/www/program -env prod`

But when I put this into my supervisor config it tells me it can't find this file

```
[program:goprogram]
command = http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:29800 home/www/program -env prod
directory = /home/www/program
enviroment=PATH='/home/www/env/bin:/usr/bin'
user = user
autorestart = true
```

Now, I assume it has to do with the `http_proxy` or syntax, but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to set up an environment variable in the command itself, you might try a different way to call said command:

```
command = /bin/sh -c 'http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:29800 home/www/program -env prod'
```

That way:

- you don't have to add that environment variable to the environment section (or the credentials would be visible to all  supervisord process' and child process’ environments)
- you set `http_proxy` only for the command to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `http_proxy` variable. Either the way @VonC described it or:

```
[program:goprogram]
command = home/www/program -env prod
directory = /home/www/program
enviroment=
    PATH='/home/www/env/bin:/usr/bin'
    http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:29800
user = user
autorestart = true
```

More information can be found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055951/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-supervisor-service).

Comment: I didn't want to go that way, because it would expose the proxy credentials to every supervisord children process. Not very good.