# Run Django workers servers with supervisor?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm trying to deploy my Django application with supervisor. When I launch supervisor it starts daphne correctly, however the worker servers are not launched.

Here's a code sample of supervisor.conf (the workers block):

```
[program:runworker]
command=python /home/django/environment/myproject/manage.py runworker
stopsignal=KILL
killasgroup=true
```

The browser waits a long time and then it shows:

```
 503 Service Unavailable
Worker server failed to respond within time limit.
```

I could also add that if I launch the processes independently (not using any process control system ) it actually works. 
I'm behind an Nginx reverse proxy, but I don't think that's the issue at all..

Here's the output of Supervisor:

```
2016-08-17 19:01:09,439 INFO supervisord started with pid 3473
2016-08-17 19:01:10,441 INFO spawned: 'runworker' with pid 3477
2016-08-17 19:01:10,442 INFO spawned: 'daphne' with pid 3478
2016-08-17 19:01:11,421 DEBG 'daphne' stderr output:
2016-08-17 23:01:11,421 INFO Starting server at 0.0.0.0:9000, channel layer myproject.asgi:channel_layer

2016-08-17 19:01:11,519 INFO success: runworker entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-08-17 19:01:11,519 INFO success: daphne entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-08-17 19:01:11,591 DEBG 'runworker' stderr output:
2016-08-17 23:01:11,591 - INFO - runworker - Running worker against channel layer default (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer)

2016-08-17 19:01:11,592 DEBG 'runworker' stderr output:
2016-08-17 23:01:11,592 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.

This answer provides an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26732916/4193

Comment: Thanks Tim, it didn't work though. I think it's using the correct Setting module, because it's connecting to the Redis Backend which is defined for that environment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to increase time limit and increasing capacity throughput is higher than 100 messages a second

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
            "CONFIG": {
                "hosts": [(XXX, XXX)],
                "channel_capacity": {
                    "http.request": 200,
                    "websocket.send*": 20,
                },
            },
            "ROUTING": "XXXXXchannel_routing"
        },
    }
```