# Export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as environment variable in supervisor

Tags: django, virtualenv, gunicorn, supervisord

My project is based on Django, Nginx, Gunicorn and Supervisor in a Virtual env.

I export environmental variables at the end of the `./bin/activate` script. Whenever I `source` the activate file, it exports environmental variables. It's pretty cool...

My issue comes when I start the Supervisor script. It seems that the `./bin/activate` isn't sourced as Django can't get vars such as SECRET_KEY.

I heard people using a post-activate script which isn't present in my virtualenv bin dir. Am I missing something important? Why Supervisor doesn't source the `./bin/activate` script?

Here is my supervisor conf:

```
command=/opt/.virtualenvs/plcweb/bin/gunicorn plcweb.config.wsgi -c /opt/plcweb/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/opt/plcweb/project
user=bastien
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
stdout_logfile=/opt/plcweb/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile=/opt/plcweb/gunicorn.log
```

Comment: But you don't have anything in that config that calls activate. How are you expecting it to happen?

Comment: I naively supposed that installing gunicorn into the virtualenv through `pip` would have bind it to this virtualenv, to which it belongs, and therefore, in a way activate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055951/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-supervisor-service), you have a very simple solution with the `environment` directive. So to export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, supervisor conf file should be as following:

```
command=/opt/.virtualenvs/plcweb/bin/gunicorn plcweb.config.wsgi -c /opt/plcweb/gunicorn.conf.py
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.production
directory=/opt/plcweb/project
user=bastien
```