# How to pass shell environment variable to Supervisor program?

Tags: django, ansible, environment-variables, supervisord, secret-key

I have a Django app which runs on Gunicorn, and is managed by SupervisorD which is managed by Ansible.

I want Django to read the `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` variable from the environment, since I don't want to store my secret key in a config file or VCS. For that I read the key from the environment in my `settings.py`:

```python
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']
```

Looking at [Supervisor docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values) it says:

> **Note** that the subprocess will inherit the environment variables of the shell used to start “supervisord” except for the ones overridden here. See Subprocess Environment.

Here's my `supervisor.conf`:

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/.../.virtualenvs/homepage/bin/gunicorn homepage.wsgi -w 1 --bind localhost:8001 --pid /tmp/gunicorn.pid
directory=/.../http/homepage
```

When I set the variable and run Gunicorn command from the shell, it starts up just fine:

```
$ DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=XXX /.../.virtualenvs/homepage/bin/gunicorn homepage.wsgi -w 1 --bind localhost:8001 --pid /tmp/gunicorn.pid
```

However when I set the variable in the shell and restart the Supervisor service my app fails to start with error about not found variable:

```
$ DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=XXX supervisorctl restart gunicorn
gunicorn: ERROR (not running)
gunicorn: ERROR (spawn error)
```

Looking at Supervisor error log:

```
  File "/.../http/homepage/homepage/settings.py", line 21, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']
  File "/.../.virtualenvs/homepage/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DJANGO_SECRET_KEY'
[2017-08-27 08:22:09 +0000] [19353] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19353)
[2017-08-27 08:22:09 +0000] [19349] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-08-27 08:22:09 +0000] [19349] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I have also tried restarting the supervisor service, but same error occurs:

```
$ DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=XXX systemctl restart supervisor
...
INFO exited: gunicorn (exit status 3; not expected)
```

My question is how do I make Supervisor to "pass" environment variables to it's child processes?

Comment: This is completely the wrong way round. Supervisor doesn't run under your user ID. You should be setting the variable in the supervisor config, not the other way round.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have my supervisor config in VCS, so I can't put my secret key in it.

Comment: Reading `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` enviroment variable is not related to supervisor conf. Not sure how you are doing it but you can use `os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')` to assign value in our django settings file. you can also use package like `django-environ` for that.

Comment: @demonno I already have `os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')` in Django's `settings.py`. The problem is this variable is not being set when Gunicorn process is getting started from Supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

Create executable file similar to this and try to start it manually.
i.e create file and copy script below `/home/user/start_django.sh`

You need to fill in `DJANGODIR` and make other adjustments according to your case. also, you may need to adjust permissions accordingly.

```
#!/bin/bash

DJANGODIR=/.../.../..
ENVBIN=/.../.virtualenvs/homepage/bin/bin

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source $ENVBIN/activate

DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=XXX
#define other env variables if you need

# Start your Django
exec gunicorn homepage.wsgi -w 1 --bind localhost:8001 --pid /tmp/gunicorn.pid
```

If it starts manually then just use this file in your conf.

```
[program:django_project]
command = /home/user/start_django.sh
user = {your user}
stdout_logfile = /var/log/django.log
redirect_stderr = true
# you can also try to define enviroment variables in this conf
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8,DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=XXX
```

## references that might be helpful,

- [Ref 1 - environment-variables](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#environment-variables)
- [Ref 2](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/242)
- [Ref 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055951/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-supervisor-service)

Comment: Hmm, so how do I manage `start_django.sh`? I can't put it in version control since it contains a secret key. I could have just as easily put my secret key in `settings.py` or `supervisor.conf`, but the problem is these files are under version control, too.

Comment: I think it is possible to add a line in proposed bash script which exports env variables from an external file(untracked by version control). But I personally would prefer to use `django-environ` which can be configured to read all variables from `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out myself. Turns out ansible has feature called Vault, which is used for exactly this kind of jobs - encrypting keys.

Now I added the vaulted secret key to ansible's host_vars, see:
[Vault: single encrypted variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_vault.html#single-encrypted-variable) and [Inventory: Splitting out host and group specific data](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data).

I added a task to my ansible playbook to copy the key file from ansible vault to the server:

```
- name: copy django secret key to server
  copy: content="{{ django_secret_key }}" dest=/.../http/homepage/deploy/django_secret_key.txt mode=0600
```

And made Django read the secret from that file:

```
with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'deploy', 'django_secret_key.txt')) as secret_key_file:
    SECRET_KEY = secret_key_file.read().strip()
```

If anyone has a simpler/better solution, please post it and I will accept it as the answer.