# Improved way to set default log channel at run time

Tags: laravel

My Laravel application supports multiple domains (see [domain-oriented Laravel)](https://freek.dev/1486-getting-started-with-domain-oriented-laravel).  I want each domain to log to a different file, as they are all quite busy and log a lot of messages.

Right now, I am using this line of code

```php
config(['logging.default' => 'app-1']);
```

in each `entry point` [1] for a given domain named `app-1` and similar lines of code for each unique app.

Of course, I have to have a section in `config/logging.php` defining each such domain-specific channel.  The number of domains is small enough and changes rarely enough that this is not a problem.

But this feels a bit hacky to me.  Is there a better way to do this?

[1]: I have to use such a line at the top-level method of any execution, so each Controller, each Command, and each Job (at a minimum) within one domain has to have that line of code to set the `default` logging channel for all subsequent calls to `Log::xxx()`.

Comment: Any reason not to just set it once in middleware?

Comment: I don't know how I would accomplish this in middleware.  Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: ```Log::setDefaultDriver('my-channel');```

Answer (score 1):

If you need something done for every request, middleware is usually the answer. So create a middleware by running `artisan make:middleware DomainLogger`. Edit it to look something like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DomainLogger
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $domain = $request->getHost();
        // use whatever logic to match these up; static map, db lookup, etc.
        $logger = match($domain) {
            'example.com' => 'foo',
            'example.net' => 'bar',
            'example.org' => 'baz',
            default => 'def',
        };
        config('logging.default', $logger);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And then register it in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```php
protected $middleware = [                                                                       
    ...
    App\Http\Middleware\DomainLogger::class,                                                              
];
```

---

The middleware above will work for all HTTP requests, including API calls, but won't help with Artisan commands or jobs.

For command line calls, you can override the default in the `.env` file as part of the command. e.g. `LOG_CHANNEL=foo artisan do:something`.

For jobs, you can have a separate queue worker for each domain, using [the `environment` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055951/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-supervisor-service) in `supervisord.conf`. If that isn't an option you'll need to save the domain into the job instance and then use the same logic as the middleware to set the value at run time.

Comment: Thanks.  That will handle my controllers, but my CLI commands and batch (scheduled) jobs need the same thing and it appears there is no middleware facility for them.

Comment: Edited my comments into the answer.